# Bison flex new line is not recognised

Tags: syntax, syntax-error, newline, bison, flex-lexer

This is my input file:

```
class Box{ 
integer x;
}
```

The parses recognises the token CLASS, IDENTIFIER, { and then it says **next token is $undefined** and then it prints **syntax error**

When the code is in one line like:

```
class Box{integer x;}
```

it works as intended...

So the main problem is how to identify the new line

**EDIT: here is a part of the flex file**

```
declarations
%%
"\n" {return (NEWLINE);  }
[ ]+ /* blank, tab, new line: eat up whitespace */  
. {return(yytext[0]);}
%%
Auxiliary functions
```

Do i need to change my blank, tab and new line code to this: ?

```
[ \t\n]+         /* blank, tab, new line: eat up whitespace */
.                    {return(yytext[0]);}
```

**edit2: my flex file is :**

```
flex
%{
#include "arxeio.tab.h"
%}
KEF [A-Z]
MIK [a-z]
NUM [0-9]
US [_]
ID [A-Z]([A-Z]*[a-z]*[0-9]*[_]*)*|[a-z]([A-Z]*[a-z]*[0-9]*[_]*)*|[_]([A-Z]*[a-z]*[0-9]*[_]*)*
AR [0-9]+
%%
":="  {return (ASSGNOP); }
char {return (CHAR);  }
else { return (ELSE);  }
if {return (IF);  }
integer {return (INTEGER); }
class {return (CLASS); }
new {return (NEW);  }
return {return (RETURN); }
void {return (VOID);  }
while {return (WHILE); }
{ID} {return(IDENTIFIER) ;}
{AR} {return (NUMBER); }
"\n"   { fputs("<<newline>>\n", stderr); return (NEWLINE); }
"\""  {return (ET);  }
"\'"  {return (ET);  }
"\0"  {return (ET);  }
"\t"  {return (ET);  }
"\\"  {return (ET);  }
[ \t\n]+ /* ignore spaces, tabulations,line breaks,blank, tab, new line: eat up whitespace*/
.                    {return(yytext[0]);}
%%
```

**my bison file is:**

```
  %{
    #include  <stdio.h>
    #include  <stdlib.h>
    #include  <string.h>
    #include   <math.h>
    #define YYDEBUG 1
    int yylex(void) ;
    extern FILE *yyout;
    int errors;
    %}
    %start program
    %token CHAR ELSE IF INTEGER CLASS NEW RETURN VOID WHILE ASSGNOP
    %token NUMBER NEWLINE
    %token IDENTIFIER
    %token KEF MIK NUM ET 
    %left  '`''~''@''#''$''^''['']''{''}'',''_''?''.'';'':'
    %left '|''&''!'
    %left '>''<''='
    %left '-''+'
    %left '*''/''%'
    %left '('')'
    %expect 32
    %%
    ...
    ...
    ...
    program : CLASS IDENTIFIER '{'NEWLINE declar'}' 
    ;

    %%

    main (int argc,char *argv[])
    {extern FILE *yyin;
    ++argv;--argc;
    yyin = fopen ( argv[0],"r");
    yydebug = 1;
    errors = 0;
    yyparse();
    }

    yyerror(char *errmsg)
    {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n",errmsg);
    }
```

Comment: Normally, your lexical scanner will 'skip' newlines, treating them them the same as blanks except for incrementing the input line counter.  You might object to them appearing inside a string or character constant, of course, and they mark the ends of single-line comments, but all of that is handled inside the lexical scanner.  Since you've not shown any of your Flex code, we can't say much more.

Comment: Note that `"/n"` is *very* different from `"\n"`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the Flex code is copy'n'pasted, you've got a simple typo:

```
"/n" {return (NEWLINE);  }
```

should be:

```
"\n" { return(NEWLINE); }
```

You could help yourself debug this by using (temporarily):

```
"\n" { fputs("<<newline>>\n", stderr); return (NEWLINE); }
```

and then observing that it is never executed.

Comment: It must be a problem when i copy pasted the code.. the code is as you say so there isn't any problem there

Comment: What does your grammar do when the lexical scanner returns a NEWLINE token?  Is NEWLINE a recognized token in the language?

Comment: I have include the NEWLINE in my tokens --> `%token NEWLINE`  in my grammar and yes NEWLINE is recognized as token - can you explain please your first question?

Comment: What token is the Flex analyzer returning when you get the error?  You have ensured that every `return` inside your lexical analyzer has a `printf()` or similar so that you can see exactly what your analyzer is up to (as in my `fputs()` suggestion)?  Which value is being returned?  Your grammar doesn't seem to think that it is NEWLINE.  How have you got NEWLINE defined?  Do you have the header from the Bison grammar included in the Flex analyzer?

Comment: the problem still persists.. i have attached my bison and flex code above

Comment: Your ID rule is unnecessarily complex; you could change it to: `ID    [_A-Za-z][_A-Za-z0-9]*`.  Do you see NEWLINE being returned?  You have a blank/tab/newline rule; if there is a blank after the `{` and before the newline, then the longer rule will apply.  You should probably drop the `\n` from `[ \t\n]+`.

Comment: You also have a rule `"\t"` { return(ET); }` which would cause issues w.r.t the `[ \t\n]+` rule.  Either you need to return tabs (and newlines) or you need to ignore them.  I'd add an action like to `[ \t\n]+ { fputs("<<white space>>\n", stderr); }` to print when the white space rule triggers.  In case of doubt, do a print like this for every rule in your lexical analyzer.

Comment: i have added `fputs("<<white space>>\n", stderr); }` and it prints white space but when it goes to the next line it says `"the next token is undefined"` so i think there must be a problem with new line

Answer (score 1):

Since you have this rule: `"/n" {return (NEWLINE);  }`, you obviously need to specify that `NEWLINE` follows `{` in your grammar; which I guess you didn't and which is understandable.

Thus, you need to use these rules

```
[ \t\n]+ /* ignore spaces, tabulations and line breaks */
.        {return(yytext[0]);}
```

Comment: i had first this 

`program  : CLASS IDENTIFIER '{ ' declar ....`

and i changed to 

`program  : CLASS IDENTIFIER '{ ' NEWLINE declar ....`

and still the same error after the parser recognise the `{` symbol it throws `next token is $undefined` and then it `stops`

Comment: Is the line break detected? What happens when you put a `puts` before `return (NEWLINE);`?

Comment: the problem still persists.. i have attached my bison and flex code above

Comment: I can't see where can the problem come from. Can you remove the lexer rule for `"\n"`, move `[ \t\n]+` to the top and try again? Also remove `NEWLINE` from your grammar.